# PHP return specific number of nodes?

Tags: php, xml

If I have a large xml file with this format:

```
<person>
   <attribute>value</attribue>
</person>
<person>
   <attribute>value</attribue>
</person>
<person>
   <attribute>value</attribue>
</person>
```

goes on for hundreds of thousands of `<person>` records....

How can I, using php, echo out to file/return 'person' 1-10, then 11-20, etc..

I have found a ton of examples (xpath, etc..) returning all nodes or node subsets, but no examples of returning a specific range of nodes.

My specific file has hundreds of thousands of `<person>` nodes.  I want to output in xml format `<person>`s 1-50,000, then 50,001-100,000, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be fairly simple.  I couldn't find a specific example online, but I managed to piece together a few different examples into what I needed:

```
<?php

$xml = simplexml_load_file('somexmlfile.xml');

$result = $xml->xpath('/enterprise/person[position()>=1 and position()<=10000]')
;

while(list( , $node) = each($result)) {
    echo $node->asXML();
}
?>
```